# Converting Dytypes of a corrupted .xls

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code is mentioned as below. `df2` is assigned to corrupted .xls file. I can only read it by `pd.read_html`. How can I print `dtypes` of an xls file which can only be read by `pd.read_html`? Maybe there is a way to assign `dtypes` or convert it to a proper extension.

`Code`

```
system_username= os.environ['USERNAME']
df1 = pd.read_excel(r"D:\Users"+"\\"+system_username+"\Desktop\SENARYOANALIZ\ORNEKLEM_MERGED.xls")
df2 = pd.read_html(r"D:\Users"+"\\"+system_username+"\Desktop\SENARYOANALIZ\Arama_Listesi.xls") 
df2.dtypes
```

After `df2.dtypes`, I get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtypes'
```

Comment: If `read_html` works it's not an Excel file at all. It's an HTML file with a fake extension. This is a common lazy hack by used by people/sites that don't know about eg `xlsxwriter` in Python, SheetJS in Javascript or `Epplus` in C#.  `xls` is an (obsolete) binary format, while `xlsx` is a ZIP file containing XML files. If the file is corrupt, you can't read it at all.

Comment: What happens if you open that file with a text editor like Notepad? What does the file contain? If the file is a CSV or HTML, there are no types. Everything is a string. You'll have to specify the column types explicitly

Comment: PS: `xls` *really* is obsolete. It was replaced by `xlsx` back in 2007, a format built to allow interoperability. That's 14 years ago. Cloud services like Google Docs or even Microsoft's Excel Online don't accept `xls` files except in paid subscriptions. There's absolutely no reason to produce `xls` files in 2021 except inertia - or ignorance. No Excel version still in use requires `xls`. Every Excel version would display a compatibility warning if you opened or saved an `xls` file.

Comment: Actually .xls file which I read by read_html can be opened from windows explorer with "the file format and extension of .... The file courrupted or unsafe" . After I push yes button excel is opened without problem. When I open it with notepad, it seems more likely an html file like that :   <div>
 <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>

Comment: So you see that this really isn't an Excel file, it's an HTML with a fake extension. And Excel does have a problem, which is why it warns this isn't a valid Excel file. After that, Excel will *import* the HTML data as best as it can. There are no types in that text file, it's just text. Excel will treat this the same as a CSV file - it will try to guess the field types from their formats, based on the current user's locale. This can easily fail though